# PHP assign to an array only if the value exists

Tags: php

I am currently using this code to assign a variable into the array only if it does not carry a null reference. Is their any shortcut/alternative method?

```
if (!is_null($foo)) {
    $var['foo'] = $foo;
}

if (!is_null($bar)) {
    $var['bar'] = $bar;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with it? It is perfectly clear what the code does; what would be the point of a shortcut/alternative?

Comment: do you want it to look shorter? you can use ternary operators then.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen nothing wrong with it, I was just expecting short assignment logic. :)

Comment: @BurningCrystals Ternary operators still expect something to be assigned to the index/variable, for eg. in my case if $var2 is null then $combinations['var2'] must not exist!

Comment: Do you need to do this with a bunch of variables in a row? Is that why you want to shorten it, or is this more of a general question? Anyway, if you do need to do it with multiple variables, you could loop over the variable names and use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Looks pretty short to me. How about a one-liner? -- `if (!is_null($foo)) $var['foo'] = $foo;`

Answer (score 3):

Well you *could* use the ternary operator as a “shortcut”:

```
is_null($foo) ?: $var['foo'] = $foo;
```

– but I would not really recommend this.

It works because `$var['foo'] = $foo` in itself is a valid expression – but is it kinda “perverting” the whole concept of the operator a bit.

---

Edit: As other have asked in comments as well, a little more context would be helpful. If you are not asking this out of pure curiosity, but for example because you have to do this for multiple variables – then putting them all into the array in any case, and then using `array_filter` to “throw away” the `null` values afterwards might be more straight forward …

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = 'var';
For ($x = 1; $x < 3; $x++){
  if (!is_null(${$a.$i})) {
    $combinations[$a.$i] = ${$a.$i};
  }
}
```